# How to plot a heat map with different sizes of rectangles in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, heatmap

I have a dataframe looks like below:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4], 'grade':[98,50,10,100], 'c':[1000,29,69,150]})
```

I want to plot a heatmap with sub-rectangles that their sizes represent the values from column 'c' and the colors represent the values from 'grade'

If it is too complicated then I can just go with colors and grade pair and not the size and "c"

I did some researches and found some examples with using sns.heatmap, but I could not get that work.

Comment: how do you want the individual datapoints oriented?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need heatmap, you need [treemap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treemapping).
Based on [this link](https://python-graph-gallery.com/202-treemap-with-colors-mapped-on-values/), you can use [squarify](https://github.com/laserson/squarify) like this:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import squarify # pip install squarify (algorithm for treemap)&lt;/pre&gt;
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4], 'grade':[98,50,10,100], 'c':[1000,29,69,150]})

# Create a dataset:
my_values=df.c # YOUR VALUES
 
# create a color palette, mapped to these values
cmap = matplotlib.cm.Blues
mini=min(my_values)
maxi=max(my_values)
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=mini, vmax=maxi)
colors = [cmap(norm(value)) for value in my_values]
 
# Change color
squarify.plot(sizes=my_values, alpha=.8, color=colors )
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image: treemap]